# laravel ->get() not returning relations properly

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, conditional-statements

I have a conditional query that works in my index controller that should return eloquent relationships but does not always return an accessible array index:

```
$customers = Customer::with('orders', 'regions')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->whereHas('regions', function($query)
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $current_user = User::with('roles')->where('id', '=', $user_id)->latest()->first();
        $role_name = $current_user->roles[0]->name;
        if($role_name == 'admin_master'){$query->whereIn('region', array(11, 7));}
    }
    )->get();
```

**The problem is the related array is not always accessible eg order[1] and displays oddly when I dd($customers);**

```
#relations: array:5 [▼
    "orders" => Collection {#442 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Order {#446 ▶}
        1 => Order {#447 …25}
      ]
    }
```

Comment: try `first` instead of `get`. The `get` returns a collection.

Comment: I need a collection though to return all customers not just one in my index

Comment: Then try this `get()->toArray()`.

Comment: That worked, can you respond as an answer so I can mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future users, the `get` method gets the results as a collection. You can chain the `toArray()` method on it to convert it into an array.

So it will be something like `$query->get()->toArray()`